# Do we use abstract algebra in real life?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Do we use abstract algebra in real life?

Is there any application of abstract algebra in real life?

Comment: This is surely a duplicate. It should be closed, before the same answers will be written over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cryptography is the prime example, especially research in elliptic curve cryptography requires a great deal of algebraic number theory and the likes. Lie group theory is used to decribe symmetries in quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

Cryptography (think interned security) and error-correcting codes both can make use of abstract algebra.