# How can we apply Algebra in our life??

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question

We all know that Math is the science's mother and it's applied in all areas,
I have an idea about where functions and geometry calculus ans stats are applied (in economic, banks, building ...), but I have no idea where can we apply algebra in real life, I mean like groups, rings and polinomials, I try to think where it could be usefull but I i find nothing.

I was thinking that if I am studying groups and rings only to teach people those notions which will also teach other's then it has no sence !!!!!!!!

any body give me some uses of groups and rings in the daily life 
thanks

Comment: Yeah they probably said the same things about Maxwell's equations.

Comment: Have you already search for some anwsers of your question on this website ? I think this is a duplicate question see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966917/do-we-use-abstract-algebra-in-real-life)  and  [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65300/real-world-uses-of-algebraic-structures) , [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324253/are-there-real-world-applications-of-finite-group-theory) , [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83837/what-is-a-real-world-application-of-polynomial-factoring) for example

Comment: @Nizar they are talking about graphs but what i wanted to know is about groups and rings which don't use graphs or calculis

Comment: I use the Abel-Ruffini-Theorem occasionally to point out that numerics have a fundamental value (apart from speed)

Answer (score 5):

I think it depends on your life. A very few people (in the big picture) actively use abstract algebra day to day. When we teach the subject, we're trying to train those people.

As a (somewhat) practical matter, X-ray crystallography depends pretty heavily on group theory, as I recall, and it's used to do all sorts of science that have an impact on your daily life.

But you might as well ask "How do we apply biochemistry in daily life?" The answer is "not at all, but it has a huge impact nonetheless, since most medicines depend on it." So all you really need is for a few people to apply biochem well, and the fact that the rest of us don't do so is actually a *good* thing: it shows that specialization has worked. Kinda like being an airline pilot. I can't fly a 747, and chances are that you can't either, but that's no reason to stop training pilots. :)

Why should *you* study abstract algebra? Well, that's a choice you're making, perhaps to enjoy understanding something that some people find inherently beautiful or at least intriguing, or perhaps to train to be one of those people whose daily life's work *does* depend on knowing that stuff.

Comment: to be fair: there is the tiny, subtle difference that your life depends upon your own biochemistry (granted, you do not have to understand it)

Answer (score 2):

Not always is pure maths used in daily life.You may read the book-A Mathematician's Apology by G.H. Hardy which talks on this issue.He says that there are certain branches of mathematics which are also called pure maths is where the real beauty of mathematics lies but they are not used in our daily lives.They help to change the view you have towards the world and your perception.

You may find the book interesting but this book has also been criticised a lot by some people.Some complex branches of number theory do have application in Information Technology that affects out daily life.For eg. use in e-mails.

Comment: Note that what area of maths are "useless" is highly depedent on evolution of global science. Prime factorization was once just a little game without real world implication... Things like category theoryhave applications in datamining, something totally unconceivable 50 years ago

Comment: Well, Hardy said, "No one has yet discovered any warlike purpose to be served by the theory of numbers or relativity, and it seems unlikely that anyone will do so for many years."  As the [Wikipedia article notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Mathematician's_Apology), "Since then number theory was used to crack German enigma codes and much later, figure prominently in public-key cryptography."

Comment: @Tryss I think the word you're looking for is [inconceivable](https://youtu.be/Z3sLhnDJJn0). :)

Comment: @SpamIAm : thanks ! English is not my native language, so sometimes I write funny stuff.